# VHDL - Debounce Button Press

Tags: switch-statement, vhdl, fpga

I have the following button press logic in my code. I have tried debouncing it using a wait delay, but the compiler will not allow this. I have four push buttons on my FPGA, which the "key" array below reflects:

```
process(clock)
        begin
            if rising_edge(clock) then
                if(key(3)/='1' or key(2)/='1' or key(1)/='1' or key(0)/='1') then --MY ATTEMPT AT DEBOUNCING
                    wait for 200 ns; ----MY ATTEMPT AT DEBOUNCING
                    if (key(3)='1' and key(2)='1' and key(1)='0' and last_key_state="1111" and key(0)='1') then
                        ...
                    elsif (key(3)='1' and key(2)='1' and key(1)='1' and key(0)='0' and last_key_state="1111") then  
                        ...
                    elsif (key(3)='0' and key(2)='1' and key(1)='1' and key(0)='1' and last_key_state="1111") then
                        ...
                    elsif (key(3)='1' and key(2)='0' and key(1)='1' and key(0)='1' and last_key_state="1111") then
                        ...
                    end if;
                    last_key_state<=key;
                end if;
            end if;
    end process;
```

Can anyone give some really simple example code showing how I could debounce a setup like the one I have above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because of wait ... wait is not synthesizeable.

I would do it with a simple counter. So you can use the same code for different clock speeds by adjusting the counter.

```
-- adjust the counter to you special needs
-- depending on how good your buttons are hardware debounced
-- you can easily think in ms
signal counter : std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0) := "10000000";

process 
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then --You're clock
      if(key(3) = '0') or (key(2) = '0') or (key(1) = '0') or (key(0) = '0') then
        start_debouncing <= '1';
        key_vector_out <= key(3) & key(2) & key(1) & key(0); 
      end if;

      if(start_debouncing = '1') then
        key_vector_out <= "0000";
        counter <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(counter) - 1);                        
      end if;

      if(counter = "00000000") then
        counter <= "10000000";
        start_debouncing <= '0';
      end if;
end process;
```

Your code can produce another problem.
What will happen if you button is released so your input is .. key = "0000" .. right you never get you output. Perhaps it will work 99 out of 100 times but you can get an really hard to find error.

Comment: I think you mean "wait for time" is *not* synthesisable.  `wait for rising_edge(clk)` for example *is*

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "What will happen if you button is released so your input is .. key = "0000" .."? My button is set up such that a value of 0 means it is pressed, and 1 means it isn't pressed.

Comment: the _last_key_state<=key_ assignment is inside your _if(key(3)... then_
even your _wait for xxxns_ would work it can happen that the assignment can not be done because the if statement is false

Answer (score 2):

Well if you think about how you would do this with real electronics you would probably use a capacitor.. which has a charging time. Same idea applies here, just figure out the time your switch is bouncing (usually a function of clock speed) and then actually set the register.

[Simple Example With a 4-Bit Shift Register](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=941196)

So you'd put this between your switch and any other logic blocks

```
process 
  begin
   if rising_edge(clock) then --You're clock

     SHIFT_PB(2 Downto 0) <= SHIFT_PB(3 Downto 1); --Shifting each cycle
     SHIFT_PB(3) <= NOT PB; --PB is the pre-bounced signal

     If SHIFT_PB(3 Downto 0)="0000" THEN --once the bounce has settled set the debounced value
      PB_DEBOUNCED <= '1'; 
     ELSE 
      PB_DEBOUNCED <= '0'; 
   End if;
end process;
```

Its basically delaying your signal 4 clock cycles (what you were trying to do with the wait).

Comment: I'm a bit new to VHDL, so I don't completely understand the code you provided. What is "clock_100Hz'EVENT"? Also, how would I adjust that code to fit a 50 MHz clock?

Comment: That's just a different syntax for the clock rising and clock falling.

With your circuit you could just use the rising edge syntax if you like that better, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for this. A couple of questions: by pre-bounced signal, do you mean the button signal initially sampled when the clock edge rises? Also, do you think it would make more sense in my case to make "PB_DEBOUNCED" a variable rather than a signal? That way, I can do something like "if(PB_DEBOUNCED='1') then ...do the rest of my code... end if;" immediately after the code you just posted.

Comment: PB is the prebounced signal, yes. You could do that but you can just as easily check the logic level from a signal as well.

Answer (score 1):

Others have shown the way with counters... you also need to synchronise the signal to the clock before feeding it to the counter, otherwise occasionally, the signal will get to different parts of the counter at different times, and the counter will count incorrectly.

Whether this matters depends on the application - if correct operation is important, it is important to synchronise correctly!